# Transmission fluid and filter change: Miles or time? Or both?

Tags: b-body, 4l60e

I'm pretty sure the service schedule for replacing the transmission filter for a 94-96 B-Body with a 4L60E automatic transmission is an interval in miles only.  I don't have the number handy at the moment, and a quick search didn't turn up a definitive number.  I'll update later with the exact number from the FSM.

Assuming the vehicle is a Garage Queen that gets very few miles put on it, should the fluid and / or filter be changed on a time interval instead?  If so, I suspect the filter would be good longer than the fluid.  For a filter with maybe 15,000 miles on it, would it be ok to change the fluid without dropping the pan and changing the filter?  Via [incremental pumping](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/4l60e-fluid-change) out of one of the cooler lines?

This application does have a an oil-to-air transmission cooler.  Does that have any impact on the life of the fluid?  Especially if the vehicle is driven long enough to boil moisture out of the fluid occasionally?

Answer (score 2):

To tell you specific details, like when it should be changed, I'll need a specific model. "94-96 B-Body" covers a pretty good range (Impala, Impala SS, Caprice).

I will warn you, though. Most cars (and trucks these days) don't have a plug built into the transmission pan to let the fluid drain, so you'll more than likely have to drop the pan anyway.

Looking at:

[image: 4L60E Transmission Picture]

It seems that this may be the case with this particular transmission.

Comment: The only problem with that is that it will probably back up through the dipstick before you can get it to go into the pan. If you have something to pressurize it as you're putting it in, you might be able to get it done that way. The cooler output is supplied fluid by the pump inside, so there's no way you're going to be able to take it off and it just run out.

Comment: Also, I say that I'll need a specific model because I can't find a manual directly from GM that mentions how often you should change it. The owner's manual should say, which is why I was asking for a specific model. Just because the transmission *seems* the same for all models, it could be different as far as pan size and all. I know this transmission was used in quite a few models, other than 94-96 B-Body cars.

Comment: Just be sure to post whatever solution you find here and select it as the answer. I'd like to know how you do it myself.

Comment: I'm not sure about the filter in those, but I will tell you that we have a drag car with a [powerglide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerglide) that sits up when it's not being used, and the filter on it is hardly ever changed. We changed the transmission fluid in it a few weeks ago for the first time in a year. The filter was fine, so it still hasn't been replaced in almost 4 years.